# Is it possible to restrict the developer console for internal user

Tags: user

I have created the internal user under Administrator user

when i click login with the Adminstrator user then i click login for internal user from administrator user

[image]

it is showing developer console:

[image]

Then i login with the username id and password of internal user seperately it is not showing developer console:

[image]

How they restricted, please anyone Guide me for the Answer

Comment: Does the Administrator profile have `Author Apex` enabled?

Comment: Apart from `Author Apex` check on `View All Data` permission on user profile

Comment: Author apex  and View all data are enabled for system administrator profile ,if enabled means it wont show ah?@Adrian Larson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in [Open the Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_opening.htm&language=en_US&type=0), your user's profile, or an added permission set, must include the System Permission "View All Data." I've tested this in the past, and it is indeed the minimum permissions necessary to view the Developer Console at all. It is not sufficient to have View All Data on some or all objects, as the Developer Console specifically checks the *PermissionsViewAllData* permission.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @sfdcfox answer, it is worth noting that for Professional Edition, you don't get Developer Console at all but if you purchase the separate API-enabled option at a modest fee, Developer Console becomes available to your System Administrators with:

- Access to the Query Editor
- Ability to create VF pages/components and Lightning Apps, Components, Interface, Event, Tokens
- Set debug logs
- Run tests
- Manage workspaces
- Inspect logs
- Monitor deployments

You can't, however, with this API-enabled feature, author any Apex or run execute anonymous.